# Sum up a newly inserted blank row

Tags: excel, vba

I have 13 worksheets with similar data (each worksheet contains data for a different client).

I need to do all these steps for each worksheet:

1. Sort Data in Column "D" - Working
2. Insert an empty row in each worksheet when a value has changed in column "D" - Working
3. When a value has changed in Column "D" and I insert the empty row, all rows with same value in column "D" should Sum up in Column "K".

In the screenshot below you can see the result of my code: a new row inserted after a value has changed in column "D". The red cells are what I need to do - Sum up.

Screenshot with SumUp
[image: Screenshot with SumUp]

I run the below code after I sort all worksheets:

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChangeColumnD()

'--- INSERT CLEAR ROWS

  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long
  Const DataCol As String = "D"
  Const StartRow = 2
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, DataCol).End(xlUp).Row
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For X = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
    If Cells(X, DataCol).Value <> Cells(X - 1, DataCol) Then Rows(X).Insert
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I need to sum up after inserting the row.

Comment: Sumif() should do the trick.  that's just a formula in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should help you achieve your expected results, when you insert a new row it adds a SumIf formula to that row summing the values from Column D, and finally it will do the same for the last row on your sheet:

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChangeColumnD()

'--- INSERT CLEAR ROWS
  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long
  Const DataCol As String = "D"
  Const StartRow = 2
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, DataCol).End(xlUp).Row
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For X = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
    If Cells(X, DataCol).Value <> Cells(X - 1, DataCol).Value Then
        Rows(X).Insert
        Cells(X, "K").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-7],R[-1]C[-7],C[-7])"
    End If
  Next
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, DataCol).End(xlUp).Row
  Cells(LastRow + 1, "K").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-7],R[-1]C[-7],C[-7])"
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier,

I changed in your code:

"=SUMIF(C[-7],R[-1]C[-7],C[-7])"

to:

"=SUMIF(C[-7],R[-1]C[-7],C[-0])"

... and it working as i want.

Can you please advise how to apply this also to SumUp Column "J" and column "L" and column "P"?

Thanks,

Peter.

Comment: If my answer has helped, please could you mark my response as an answer? Thanks :) Regarding your comment I will reply when I'm back on the laptop..

Comment: Marked. I also already figured out how to apply your code for another columns, so thanks Xabier for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this put the code on your worksheet this will detect cell changes on column4 which is D. The active cell is for the cell that changed  and maybe you can put your logic in the if statement any problems please shout

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     If (Target.Column = 4) Then
     'MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
      ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Insert
      End If
      End Sub
```